# TypeError: state.confirmed.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, fetch, rendering

**I try to fetch data from one API on Reacts. I tried every single possibility to render the data on browser but I don't know what I am doing wrong?**

**This is app.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { stat } from "fs";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [state, setstate] = useState({
    confirmed: "",
    recovered: "",
    death: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    coronaData();
  }, []);
  const coronaData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://w3qa5ydb4l.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/finnishCoronaData"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data.confirmed);
      setstate({
        confirmed: data,
        recovered: data.recovered,
        death: data.death === null ? null : alert("Lucikily No-one died")
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, "FAILED TO FETCH");
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.confirmed.map(list => {
        return (
          <ul>
            <li>{list.healthCareDistrict}</li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Ignore this message, In order to post this question, I need to write more. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are using an empty string as default value for `state.confirmed` in `useState()`. Technically `.map()` can be used on arrays only that caused the error because the app tried to call on an empty string.

I would change to an `[]` when initially defining:

```
const [state, setstate] = useState({
    confirmed: [],
    recovered: "",
    death: ""
  });
```

I believe this change also applies for `recovered` as well later. Currently you are not using in your code as it seems.

I hope this helps!